# Append same text to every cell in a column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

How can I append text to every cell in a column in Excel? I need to add a comma (",") to the end.

**Example:**

`email@address.com` turns into `email@address.com,`

**Data Sample:**

```
m2engineers@yahoo.co.in
satishmm_2sptc@yahoo.co.in
threed_precisions@rediffmail.com
workplace_solution@yahoo.co.in
threebworkplace@dataone.in
dtechbng@yahoo.co.in
innovations@yahoo.co.in
sagar@mmm.com
bpsiva@mmm.com
nsrinivasrao@mmm.com
pdilip@mmm.com
vvijaykrishnan@mmm.com
mrdevaraj@mmm.com
b3minvestorhelpdesk@mmm.com
sbshridhar@mmm.com
balaji@mmm.com
schakravarthi@mmm.com
srahul1@mmm.com
khramesh2@mmm.com
avinayak@mmm.com
rockindia@hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 239, accepted):

See if this works for you.

- All your data is in column A (beginning at row 1).
- In column B, row 1, enter      =A1&","
- This will make cell B1 equal A1 with a comma appended.
- Now select cell B1 and drag from the bottom right of cell down through all your rows (this copies the formula and uses the corresponding column A value.)
- Select the newly appended data, copy it and paste it where you need using `Paste -> By Value`

That's It!

Comment: The last step description seems incomplete.  I had to actually copy cell B1, then select the rest of the cells below it, and then paste.

Comment: Then, for anyone who doesn't know, you can copy and `Paste Special...` > `Values` to move the resulting values back to your original column without the formula destroying them.

Comment: What if you want to remove something?

Answer (score 26):

It's a simple "&" function.

```
=cell&"yourtexthere"
```

Example - your cell says Mickey, and you want Mickey Mouse. Mickey is in A2. In B2, type

```
=A2&" Mouse"
```

Then, copy and "paste special" for values.

```
B2 now reads "Mickey Mouse"
```

Answer (score 24):

It's simple...

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, ",")
```

**Example**: if email@address.com is in the A1 cell then write in another cell: **=CONCATENATE(A1, ",")**

email@address.com    After this formula you will get   **email@address.com,**

**For remove formula**: copy that cell and use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> or paste special value.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to use extra columns or VBA if you only want to add the character for *display purposes*.

As [this post](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/combine-text-and-numbers-HP010062736.aspx) suggests, all you need to do is:

1. Select the cell(s) you would like to apply the formatting to
2. Click on the `Home` tab
3. Click on `Number`
4. Select `Custom`
5. In the `Type` text box, enter your desired formatting by placing the number zero inside whatever characters you want.

**Example** of such text for formatting:

- If you want the cell holding value `120.00` to read `$120K`, type `$0K`

Answer (score 4):

Pretty simple...you could put all of them in a cell using the concatenate function:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, ", ", A2, ", ", and so on)
```

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the column and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Find and replace

Find ".com"

Replace ".com, "

And then one for .in

Find and replace

Find ".in"

Replace ".in, "

Answer (score 2):

Simplest of them all is to use the "Flash Fill" option under the "Data" tab.

1. Keep the original input column on the left (say column A) and just add a blank column on the right of it (say column B, this new column will be treated as output).
2. Just fill in a couple of cells of Column B with actual expected output. In this case:

   ```
         m2engineers@yahoo.co.in,
         satishmm_2sptc@yahoo.co.in,
   ```
3. Then select the column range where you want the output along with the first couple of cells you filled manually ... then do the magic...click on "Flash Fill".

It basically understands the output pattern corresponding to the input and fills the empty cells.

Answer (score 1):

Select the range of cells, type in the value and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This, of course, is true if you want to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this for another answer:

You would call it using the form using your example: `appendTextToRange "[theRange]", ","`.

```
Sub testit()
    appendTextToRange "A1:D4000", "hey there"
End Sub


Sub appendTextToRange(rngAddress As String, append As String)

    Dim arr() As Variant, c As Variant
    arr = Range(rngAddress).Formula

    For x = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For y = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            Debug.Print arr(x, y)
            If arr(x, y) = "" Then
                arr(x, y) = append
            ElseIf Left(arr(x, y), 1) = "=" Then
                arr(x, y) = arr(x, y) & " & "" " & append & """"
            Else
                arr(x, y) = arr(x, y) & " " & append
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Range(rngAddress).Formula = arr

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the text/value in the first cell, then copy the cell, mark the whole colum and 'paste' the copied text/value.

This works in Excel 97 - sorry no other version available on my side...

Answer (score 0):

This is addition to @Edward-Leno 's answer for more detail/explanation and cases where the text cells are ***formulas*** instead of values, and you want to ***retain the original formula***.

Suppose your cells look like this (formulas)

> ="email" & "@" & "address.com"

> =A1 & "@" & C1

instead of this (values)

> email@address.com

If "email" and "address.com" were some cells like A1 is the email and C1 is the address.com part, then you'd have something like *=A1&"@"&C1* which would be important to retain since A1 and C1 might not be constants and can change, so the comma-concatenated values would change, like if C1 is "gmail.com", "yahoo.com", or something else based on its formula.

**Values method**: The following **steps will successfully append text but only keep the value** using a scratch column (this works for rows, too, but for simplicity, the directions are for columns)

1. Assume column A is your data.
2. In scratch column B, start anywhere like the top of column B such as at B1 and put this formula:

> =A1&","

Essentially, the "&" is the concatenation operator, combining two strings together (numbers are converted to strings). The "," can be adjusted to ", " if you want a space after the comma.

3. Copy the cell B1 and copy it down to all other cells in column B, either by clicking at the bottom right of cell B1 and dragging down, or copying with "Ctrl+C" or right-click > "Copy".
4. Paste B1 to all cells in column B with "Ctrl+V" or right-click > "Paste Options:" > "Paste". You should see the data looking like you intended.
5. Copy all cells in column B and paste them to where you want via right-click > "Paste Options:" > "Values". We select values so it doesn't mess up any formatting or conditional formatting

**Formula retention method:** The following **steps will successfully retain the original formula**. The process is similar to the values method, and only *step 2*, the formula used to concatenate the comma, changes.

1. Assume column A is your data.
2. In scratch column B, start anywhere like the top of column B such as at B1 and put this formula:

> =FORMULATEXT(A1)&","

FORMULATEXT() grabs the formula of the cell as opposed to the value of it, so a simple example would be that it grabs *=2+2* instead of *4*, or *=A1 & "@" & C1* where A1 is "Bob" and C1 is "gmail.com" instead of *Bob@gmail.com*.

**Note:** This formula only works for Excel versions 2013 and greater. For alternative equivalent solutions for Excel 2010 and older, see this superuser answer: https://superuser.com/a/894441/495155

3. Copy the cell B1 and copy it down to all other cells in column B, either by clicking at the bottom right of cell B1 and dragging down, or copying with "Ctrl+C" or right-click > "Copy".
4. Paste B1 to all cells in column B with "Ctrl+V" or right-click > "Paste Options:" > "Paste". You should see the data looking like you intended.
5. Copy all cells in column B and paste them to where you want via right-click > "Paste Options:" > "Values". We select values so it doesn't mess up any formatting or conditional formatting

Answer (score -3):

Type it in one cell, copy that cell, select all the cells you want to fill, and paste.

Alternatively, type it in one cell, select the black square in the bottom-right of that cell, and drag down.